# The transfer function of a linearized system in state-space representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linearized-theory

I have physical system that can be described by a non linear equation system. I would like to get the transfer function of the linearized system.

Let $x(t)$ a state variable, $u(t)$ input and $y(t)$ output.

I linearized the differential equations at $x=x_s$ and got the following state-space representation
$$\Delta y(t) = C\cdot \Delta x(t)$$
$$ \dot{\Delta x}(t) =A\cdot \Delta x(t) + B \cdot \Delta u(t).$$

with $\Delta x=x-x_s$, $\Delta y=y-y_s$ and $\Delta u=u-u_s$.

Next I tried to Laplace transform the two equations
$$\Delta Y(s) = C\cdot \Delta X(s)$$
$$ s\cdot\Delta X(s) - x_s =A\cdot \Delta X(s) + B \cdot \Delta U(s)$$

which resulted in the following transfer function

$$ \frac{\Delta Y(s)}{\Delta U(s)} = \frac{B\cdot C\cdot \Delta X(s)}{s\cdot\Delta X(s) - x_s - A\cdot \Delta X(s)}.$$

My problem is that the state variable won't cancel out. I think I might be off  the track.

Comment: I think I can assume the linearized system is a LTI system. That makes the solution very easy. I'll have tomorrow another look at this.